# Photo Swipe with target not working on jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I am using Photo Swipe ( http://www.photoswipe.com/ ) in my jQuery Mobile page.
I want to show a thumbnail view of the images on load.
On click of the thumbnail, takes the user to the swipe enabled gallery which occupies 30% of the screen height.
I want to show some other content to the bottom of that.
I am using PhotoSwipe **version 3.0.5** and tried specifying the **TARGET**. But is not responding.
Below are the js files, code used

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="photoswipe/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"><script>
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe({ 
  enableMouseWheel: false , 
  enableKeyboard: false 
  }); 
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role = "page" data-add-back-btn = "true" id = "mainGallery">
        <div data-role = "header" data-theme = "a">
            <h1>Gallery</h1>            
        </div>
        <div data-role = "content" data-theme = "c">
            <p>Hi... I am the Photo Gallery</p>
            <div class = "gallery-wrap">
                <ul class = "gallery" id="Gallery" data-role = "listview" data-inset = "true"> 
                    <li><a href="images/full/001.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="images/full/002.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme = "c" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>&copy; 2013</h4>
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

I am very much new to jQuery Mobile. Can anyone help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
(function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('div.gallery-page')
                .live('pageshow', function(e){

                    var 
                        currentPage = $(e.target),
                        options = {},
                        photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

                    return true;

                })

                .live('pagehide', function(e){

                    var 
                        currentPage = $(e.target),
                        photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                    if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                        PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                    }

                    return true;

                });

        });

    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have edited my actual code used. Can you help me modifying that.
I tried with your code and did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

hope this will helps use the script below the gallery div

`<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery2" class="gallery-page">`

`<div data-role = "header" data-theme = "a">`

`<h1>Gallery</h1>`

`</div>`

`<div data-role = "content" data-theme = "c">`

`<p>Hi... I am the Photo Gallery</p>`

`<div class = "gallery-wrap">`

`<ul class="gallery"data-role = "listview" data-inset = "true">`

`<li><a href="full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="full/001.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li>`

`<li><a href="full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="/full/001.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li>`

`</ul>`

`</div>`

`</div>`

`<div data-role="footer" data-theme = "c" data-position="fixed">`

`<h4>&copy; 2013</h4>`

`</div>`

`<script>`

`$('div.gallery-page')`
`.live('pageshow', function(e){`

`var`
`currentPage = $(e.target),`

`options = {},`

`photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a",`

`e.target).photoSwipe(options,currentPage.attr('id'));`

`return true;`

`})`

`</script>`

`</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.gallery-page').on('pagehide', function(e){
                        PhotoSwipe.unsetActivateInstance(instance);
                        PhotoSwipe.detatch(instance); 
                        return true;

                    })
```

;